# Timer to count down in VB.Net 2010?

Tags: vb.net, timer, countdowntimer

I'm trying to use a timer to count down from a specified time I choose with the time being separated into minutes and seconds using the format **MM:SS** and then stop when the time reaches **00:00**.

So far I've used a previous answer that was found on here and modified it to the best of my knowledge with counting down although I've hit a snag in which when the timer successfully starts counting down, it's delayed and out of sync when counting down the minutes.

For example, counting down from 120 seconds;

`02:00` >
`02:59` >
`02:58` >
`02:57` >
`02:56` >
`02:55`

And then when continuing to count down past 90 seconds under the same test;

`02:30` >
`01:29` >
`01:28` >
`01:27` >
`01:26` >
`01:25`

When the countdown reaches **00** or **30** seconds, it incorrectly displays the minutes left and can't understand or figure out how to fix it.

Here is my code for my Counting Timer;

```
Private Sub tmrCountdown_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
                              ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
                          Handles tmrCountdown.Tick

    SetTime = SetTime - 1
    lblTime.Text = FormatTime(SetTime)

    If SetTime = 0 Then
        tmrCountdown.Enabled = False
    End If

End Sub
```

Here is my code for the Function formatting the time;

```
Public Function FormatTime(ByVal Time As Integer) As String
    Dim Min As Integer
    Dim Sec As Integer

    'Minutes
    Min = ((Time - Sec) / 60) Mod 60

    'Seconds
    Sec = Time Mod 60

    Return Format(Min, "00") & ":" & Format(Sec, "00")

End Function
```

And here is my code for the Form Load;

```
Private Sub frmSinglePlayer_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
                                 ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
                             Handles MyBase.Load

    'Setting the time.
    SetTime = 120
    lblTime.Text = FormatTime(SetTime)
    tmrCountdown.Enabled = True

End Sub
```

I've set;

```
    Dim SetTime As Integer
```

At the top of my Public Class so I am able to input a specified time into the countdown timer. This is probably something incredibly silly and I can't figure out what it is.

Any help is greatly appreciated and please bare in mind, I am a beginner at programming and get easily confused with large walls of code. (I can barely understand the Function as it is.)

Thank you for helping!

Comment: You are assuming that the timer tick occurs exactly on the interval specified.  It doesn't.  I think if you search for countdown timer and visual basic you will find many solutions.

Comment: I have tested using different amounts of time and all have happened within the intervals I've specified. When the seconds tick from 00 to 59, the minute doesn't decrease by 1, and when the seconds tick from 30 to 29, the minute decreases by 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Play with this:

```
Public Class frmSinglePlayer

    Private TargetDT As DateTime
    Private CountDownFrom As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3)

    Private Sub frmSinglePlayer_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        tmrCountdown.Interval = 500
        TargetDT = DateTime.Now.Add(CountDownFrom)
        tmrCountdown.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub tmrCountdown_Tick(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles tmrCountdown.Tick
        Dim ts As TimeSpan = TargetDT.Subtract(DateTime.Now)
        If ts.TotalMilliseconds > 0 Then
            lblTime.Text = ts.ToString("mm\:ss")
        Else
            lblTime.Text = "00:00"
            tmrCountdown.Stop()
            MessageBox.Show("Done")
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Just tested this countdown timer out and it's absolutely fantastic! Works like a charm and no hassle.

Answer (score 1):

Take a tested sample of countdown timer. Make the changes you need(ex the format of the time).

Sub New()

```
        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

        SetTime = 70

        AddHandler dtTimer.Tick, AddressOf dtTimer_Tick
        dtTimer.Interval = New TimeSpan(0, 0, 1)
        dtTimer.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Property SetTime As Integer

    Private Sub dtTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

        Dim iMinutes As Integer
        Dim iSeconds As Integer

        If SetTime = 0 Then
            dtTimer.Stop()
            txtTime.Text = "0:0"
            Exit Sub
        End If

        SetTime -= 1
        iMinutes = Math.Floor(SetTime / 60)
        iSeconds = SetTime Mod 60

        txtTime.Text = iMinutes & ":" & iSeconds
    End Sub
```

Comment: I unfortunately got more errors with this method, although I did have a good crack at it and tried my best to modify it to work. Thank you for the help though, it gave me a better understanding of how it all works. :D

Comment: If  `dtTimer.Interval = 100` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
'the amount of time to countdown from
Dim countDownFrom As New TimeSpan(0, 0, 10) 'ten seconds
'a Stopwatch to track how long running
Dim stpw As New Stopwatch

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, _
                          e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Timer1.Interval = 250 'how often to update display
    Timer1.Start() 'start the display updater
    stpw.Reset() 'restart the stopwatch
    stpw.Start()
    'or depending on version of .Net
    'stpw.Restart
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, _
                        e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If stpw.Elapsed <= countDownFrom Then
        Dim toGo As TimeSpan = countDownFrom - stpw.Elapsed
        lblTime.Text = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", toGo.Hours, toGo.Minutes, toGo.Seconds)
    Else
        Timer1.Stop()
        stpw.Stop()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You did not include an example of the Stopwatch type, by mentioning that user must import the System.Diagnotics

Comment: @htm11h - unless the user has changed the defaults System.Diagnostics does not need to be explicitly imported.  BTW - this is over a year old.

Answer (score 1):

your mistake in your original code is that you are using the MOD operater incorrectly.

```
   'Minutes
    Min = ((Time - Sec) / 60) Mod 60

    'Seconds
    Sec = Time Mod 60
```

At 2:00 you see 2:00 because:

```
Min = ((120-00) / 60 ) MOD 60 = 2 MOD 60 = 2

Sec = 120 MOD 60 = 0
```

At 1:59 you see 2:59 because

```
Min = (119 / 60) MOD 60 = 1.98 MOD 60 = 1.98 = 2

Sec = 119 MOD 60 = 59
```

After 31 seconds your minutes changes from 2 to 1 because

```
Min = (89 / 60) MOD 60 = 1.48 MOD 60 = 1.48 = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

More simply:

```
Format((Math.Floor(lSeconds / 60)), "00") & ":" & Format((lSeconds Mod 60), "00")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Public SetTime As Integer = 0
Public Min As Integer = 0
Public Sec As Integer = 0
Public Decimaal As Decimal = 0

Public Function FormatTime(ByVal Time As Integer) As String   
  'Minutes
  Min = Fix(SetTime / 60000)
  'Decimaal
  Decimaal = (SetTime / 60000) - Min
  'Seconden
  Sec = Fix(Decimaal * 60)

  Return Format(Min, "00") & ":" & Format(Sec, "00")

End Function

Private Sub tmrCountdown_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrCountdown.Tick
        SetTime = SetTime - 1000
        lblCountdown.Text = FormatTime(SetTime)
        tmrCountdown.Enabled = True

        If SetTime = 0 Then
            tmrCountdown.Enabled = False
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes

Answer (score 0):

You could just do

```
For i = 120 to 0 step -1 
     Console.writeline(i)
Next
```

But be aware it will instantly put them on the screen and it won't do it 1 at a time

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).