# Count down timer in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, timer

In the following code I have a timer that counts down from 5 mins. I am trying to have a visual count down timer in a lbl in mm:ss but the example I used doesn't work. It counts down but doesn't update the lbl until it hits 00:00.

The asker of the following question (were I got the code) said it works perfectly but for me it doesn't at all.

[The Example I used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16628296/timer-to-count-down-in-vb-net-2010)

My code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    picLogo.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage

    'Timer until update
    tmrUpdate.Interval = 300000 '5 minutes
    TargetDT = DateTime.Now.Add(CountDownFrom)
    tmrUpdate.Enabled = True


End Sub

Private Sub tmrUpdate_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrUpdate.Tick
    Dim ts As TimeSpan = TargetDT.Subtract(DateTime.Now)
    If ts.TotalMilliseconds > 0 Then
        lblTimer.Text = ts.ToString("mm\:ss")
    Else
        lblTimer.Text = "00:00"
        tmrUpdate.Stop()
    End If



End Sub
```

Comment: you did not implement it correctly.  ***Your*** timer will go off but once.

Comment: Your interval of 300000 means it will go off once 5 mins hence.  The linked code uses a 500ms interval to actually countdown until the target is reached

Comment: Oh ok. I didn't read the question right. I though it would update the lbl as it counted down.

Comment: It **does** update the label..approx once every 500ms, until the target time is reached.  The timer interval determines the frequency of the Tick event

Comment: Be sure to upvote that answer since you found it useful

Comment: I don't think this code will work for what I am trying to do. I have lbls that get data from an excel file and the timer is supposed to indicate when the app is supposed to check for an update in the excel file. So that's where the 5 mins come in. So I need 2 timers?

Comment: If all you want to do is to know when 5 mins is up to do something, you need one timer.  If you want to display a countdown, you also only need one timer.  Instead of `tmrUpdate.Stop()` in the code, when 4 mins is up, go do your excel thing.  Then restart (?) the timer for the next cycle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer:**

Using a Async Sub I had the count down timer running while other stuff was going on in the back ground. This way the app could still be used during the `Sub Wait()` and this code also displayed the count down timer.
Used one timer on a 1 sec interval.

```
Private Async Sub DoStuff()

'Doing stuff

timeUpDate = 599
        tmrUpdate.Start()
        Application.DoEvents()
        Await Task.Run(Sub()
                           Wait()

                       End Sub)
    Loop
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrUpdate.Tick
    Dim hms = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeUpDate)
    Dim m = hms.Minutes.ToString
    Dim s = hms.Seconds.ToString

    If timeUpDate > 0 Then
        timeUpDate -= 1
        lblTimer.Text = (m & ":" & s)

    Else

        tmrUpdate.Stop()
        lblTimer.Text = "text"

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Wait()
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(600000)
End Sub
```